# How to replace version references in Renovate `postUpgradeTasks`?

Tags: renovate

I've set up [renovatebot on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/engmark/renovate) to keep package versions in [another repository](https://gitlab.com/engmark/mypy-exercises) up to date. But outside of the relevant lock file there are other files which also reference certain package versions. For example, in the [readme](https://gitlab.com/engmark/mypy-exercises/-/blob/8cdf927872925f2f66063a04a5249b2c55d0d0cf/README.md#website):

```markdown
If you don't want to install anything you can use
[mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=1.3.0&python=3.8) to
verify your type annotations in a browser.
```

The `mypy=1.3.0` part of that URL should be kept in sync with the mypy version in `poetry.lock`. Is this possible? Based on the [documentation](https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#postupgradetasks) I've come up with this naive implementation, but I'm not sure how to test it or whether it'll work:

```json
{
  "postUpgradeTasks": {
    "commands": ["sed -i -e \"s/mypy=.*&/mypy=/$(poetry show mypy | grep ' version .*' | cut --delimiter=: --fields=2 | cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=2)\" README.md"],
    "fileFilters": ["poetry.lock", "README.md"],
    "executionMode": "update"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather `postUpgradeTasks` you probably want to use a [`regexManager`](https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#regexmanagers).

If the `depName`s are identically or have the same `groupName` they also will be combined in a single PR/MR.

Comment: Thank you, that was the missing link! I've come up with [this change](https://gitlab.com/engmark/mypy-exercises/-/merge_requests/392), but I don't really know how to test it before merging.

Comment: Sadly there is no way to directly test on a branch, but you can create a separate repo to test this.

Comment: I'm afraid [you're right about testing](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/22477). :( Just gotta change the configuration and hope for the best (or spend hours setting things up to test a single change).